# GCP Log Entry Consistency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, consistency, google-cloud-logging

I am wondering about consistency of GCP Logging. Let me explain with an example. If I have a computing entity and I update its configuration, I can find a log entry in GCP logging for the modification made to the VM. However, does GCP logging guarantees the availability of the log entry right after the change or it will eventually be available?

Also, based on the above example, **if log entry becomes available eventually**, is GCP logging sequentially consistent? For instance, if two modifications are made to the VM config at time T1 (M1) and T2 (M2). Would it be possible that GCP Logging shows a log entry for M2 but not for M1 for even a short period of time? Or it is guaranteed that if GCP shows a log entry for an event at a particular time, log entries related to prior events are also listed

Answer (score 0):

For taking a quick look of the scenario, I stopped one VM from my project.Found the VM ‘stop’ event there in the Stackdriver log immediately after the operation.Also started the VM and eventually found the event ‘start’ there in the log.

According to documentation on [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry), timestamp is the time the event described by the log entry occurred. This time is used to compute the log entry's age and to enforce the logs retention period. If this field is omitted in a new log entry, then Logging assigns it the current time. Timestamps have nanosecond accuracy, but trailing zeros in the fractional seconds might be omitted when the timestamp is displayed.You can also take a look at [How-to](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/how-to) in order to get more details on cloud logging.